# Laravel 4 reCaptcha validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCAPTCHA in a contact form controller in Laravel 4.

I've saw the `Validator::extend` method, but cannot accomplish the custom validation.

Here is my current code:

```
class ContactController extends BaseController {

    protected $captcha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->captcha = new Captcha\Captcha();
        $this->captcha->setPublicKey('xxx');
        $this->captcha->setPrivateKey('xxx');
    }

    public function postIndex()
    {
        $response = $this->captcha->check();

        Validator::extend('recaptcha', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            return $response->isValid();
        });

        $validator = Validator::make(
            Input::all(),
            array(
                array('recaptcha_response_field'    => 'recaptcha'),
                array('name'                        => 'required'),
                array('email'                       => 'required|email'),
                array('message'                     => 'required')
            ),
            array(
                'recaptcha' => 'Incorrect captcha code'
            )
        );

        if ( $validator->passes() )
            return Redirect::to('contact')->with('success', 'Success');
        else
            return Redirect::to('contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

}
```

I am using this [reCaptcha lib](https://packagist.org/packages/recaptcha/php5)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it fast you could just set a custom filter, and you are good to go.

```
Route::filter('reCaptcha', function() {
        //Lib file
        require_once(app_path().'/recaptchalib.php');
        //Private and public keys
        $config  = include app_path().'/config/reCaptacha.php';
        $privatekey = $config['privateKey'];
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            //Here you can throw an exception or something 
            die("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
                    "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
        }
    });
```

Then just add the captcha in your forms and that's that, in this example I was using restful controllers so, I just added a new rule in my controller that looks like this

```
$this->beforeFilter('reCaptcha', array("only" => array(
    'postCreate',
)));
```

AT least for this task I don't see the need of using someone else's libraries, since google documentation is very clear, you could do it in 5 different ways, the one described above is the simplest and fastest one, but you could do it Asynchronously just as easy, just read the docs. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php.

Good luck :)

Comment: Of course I can do it by myself, but why should I invent the wheel again when there are already done great libraries for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I've used different [library](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha) and solved my problem

Comment: I also used the library you have indicated, it does not work.
Always get the following response: "The response field recaptcha field is required." :/

Answer (score 0):

I use this package works great with Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 :)

https://github.com/google/recaptcha